# Scroll view parallax effect

Tags: swift, layout, uiview, constraints, parallax

I made a program from one youtube channel and ran into a problem. I think that it is related to the layout. On different devices displayed differently. And can someone tell me how to fix what text will fit onto another one and how to make the image appear on the whole my CustomView.

```
import UIKit struct scrollViewDataStruct {
let title: String?
let image: UIImage?
} class ScrollController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

var scrollViewData = [scrollViewDataStruct]()

var viewTagValue = 10
var tagValue = 100

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    scrollView.delegate = self

    scrollViewData = [scrollViewDataStruct.init(title: "There was written a very large line that climbs to another line", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "knowledge_graph_logo")),
                      scrollViewDataStruct.init(title: "Second", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "knowledge_graph_logo"))]

    scrollView.contentSize.width = self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(scrollViewData.count)

    var i = 0

    for data in scrollViewData {
        let view = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 10 + (self.scrollView.frame.width * CGFloat(i)), y: 200, width: self.scrollView.frame.width - 75, height: self.scrollView.frame.height - 90))
        view.imageView.image = data.image
        view.tag = i + viewTagValue
        self.scrollView.addSubview(view)

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 20), size: CGSize.init(width: 0, height: 40)))
        label.text = data.title
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        label.sizeToFit()
        label.tag = i + tagValue

        if i == 0 {
            label.center.x = view.center.x
        } else {
            label.center.x = view.center.x - self.scrollView.frame.width / 2
        }
        self.scrollView.addSubview(label)

        i += 1
    }
}
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView == scrollView {
        for i in 0..<scrollViewData.count {
            let label = scrollView.viewWithTag(i + tagValue) as! UILabel
            let view = scrollView.viewWithTag(i + viewTagValue) as! CustomView

            var scrollContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.x + self.scrollView.frame.width
            var viewOffset = (view.center.x - scrollView.bounds.width / 4) - scrollContentOffset
            label.center.x = scrollContentOffset - ((scrollView.bounds.width / 4 - viewOffset) / 2)
        }
    }
}}class CustomView: UIView {

let imageView: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return imageView
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.addSubview(imageView)
    imageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
    imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}}
```

This is a launch on iPhone 5s

[image: This is a launch on iPhone 5s]

This is a launch on iPhone 8 plus

[image: This is a launch on iPhone 8 plus]

Comment: the problem is you're adding each new label without regard for the previously added labels. Meaning, you should keep a reference to the previous label, get it's maxX(the most right coordinate position) and then use that to determine the new x position of the next label to be added.

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing is setting the width of each UILabel to the size of the CustomView that contains the image, and setting each label's "numberOfLines" to 0 and set the lineBreak to wordWrap. This should, in theory, let the labels only be the width of the images AND let the UILabels fit the size of the text vertically, rather than horizontally - which is what sizeToFit does.